How can I show an updated header component with a user's info in Next.js?
I am currently building my first web application using the Next.js App Router. Unfortunately, I've hit a roadblock in trying to display the user's info (like a username) in the page's header. When the status of the user's session changes, the header does not update to reflect the new status. For instance, if a user signs in, they are redirected to their dashboard, but the header still shows the placeholder "Sign In" instead of a username:

When I reload the page, however, the header updates to reflect the new information:

This leads me to believe that there is an issue with the header not re-rendering upon navigation.
Currently, I have placed the header in the root template.tsx file:
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

export default function RootTemplate({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <main>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

And this is the Header.tsx file. Note that Header is a Server Component:
import styles from './Header.module.css'
import { getAccount } from '@/lib/session';

export default async function Header() {
    const name = (await getAccount())?.name ?? 'Sign in';

    return (
        <header className={styles.container}>
            <h1 className='no-margin'>BuckBook</h1>
            <h1 className='no-margin'>{name}</h1>
        </header>
    )
}

(getAccount() simply fetches the account information associated with the current session. I have verified that it works correctly at render time.)
According to the Next.js documentation, template.tsx files differ from layout.tsx files in that their children do not persist upon navigation (at least, from what I understand):

Templates are similar to layouts in that they wrap a child layout or page. Unlike layouts that persist across routes and maintain state, templates create a new instance for each of their children on navigation. This means that when a user navigates between routes that share a template, a new instance of the child is mounted, DOM elements are recreated, state is not preserved in Client Components, and effects are re-synchronized.

Thus, when I placed my Header component in template.tsx, I thought it would be re-rendered on the server with updated information and sent to the client upon navigation. However, that doesn't appear to be happening (maybe because it's a Server Component)?
To get around this, I tried to convert the Header component into a Client Component that retrieves the user's name upon rendering with a Server Action, but there was a noticeable delay in the header updating due to the latency of fetching account and session information from the database. Is there a way to make the Header component re-render to show consistently updated user information without a delay?

First of all, as I see there is no logic that requires template functionality, so in your case it is better to use layout.tsx - template vs layout.

Thus, when I placed my Header component in template.tsx, I thought it would be re-rendered on the server with updated information and sent to the client upon navigation.

Next.js Server Components render on the server only on the initial request. After that, non-static logic hydrates and works like regular React, which compares changes in the Virtual DOM and performs reconciliation.
So maybe Next doesn't see changes of username in your Header, try to use useState. But all neccessary logic to find your problem is inside Header component, so it is better for you to provide Header source code.

Hello! I have updated the question to include the Header component code. Also, does this mean that only Client Components in template.tsx files get rerendered? The documentation had me thinking that both Server and Client Components were rerendered in a template.tsx file.

As I understand even if user already authorized it shows sign in and on reload shows username? Or after sign in it won't update header?

after you convert your header into a client component, you need to wrap your compnents in any state managament to pass the data to header(context, zustand, redux), so once the user is logged in you can update you state and this state will update the data in Header to rerender.
server component by itself will render only once on server
to implement zustand :- https://zustand.docs.pmnd.rs/guides/nextjs
context in next App router: https://app-router.vercel.app/context
if you need more help I can share a repo with a simple context provider
